# Infinite sum with triangular numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking at the infinite sum, which is similar to a geometric series but with triangular numbers:
$$\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)(n+2)x^n$$
In Mathematica, I get that this sum is simply $(1-x)^{-3}$, is there a simple way to prove this? Of course this converges only for $|x|<1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1288492/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1589870/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the geometric power series and differentiate it twice:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^{2} + \ldots & \Rightarrow \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{2}} = 1 + 2x + 3x^{2} + \ldots\\\\
 & \Rightarrow \frac{2}{(1 - x)^{3}} = 1\times 2 + (2\times 3)x + (3\times 4)x^{2} + \ldots
\end{align*}

where the last series coincides with the proposed one (except for the multiplying constant).

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

For $|x|<1$ we have
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n$$
Differentiating twice we have
$$\Rightarrow 2\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
I think you can carry on from here

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You start with $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+2}$, and find the closed form as it is geometric, then taking the second derivative both sides to get the answer.